# Difference of Gaussian filtering (DoG) doesn't give the expected results

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the method from the original paper ( Enhanced Local Texture Feature Sets for Face
Recognition Under Difficult Lighting Conditions by Xiaoyang Tan and Bill Triggs) in python 3.6 and Opencv 4.2, 
 but when I applied the preprocessing to an image it didn't give the same results as in the paper
although I used the same parameters specified: 
1- for the gamma correction, gamma=0.2 
2- for the DoG, (sigma0=1, sigma1=2)
3- for the contrast equalization, tau=10 and alpha=0.1

here is the expected result and the result that i had:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNRki.jpg)     [resulted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3cWh.jpg)   [expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtBkK.jpg)

and here is the code that I used :

```
img_original = cv.imread('C:/Users/Ouss/Desktop/TP-LTP/face.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# gamma correction
lookUpTable = np.empty((1, 256), np.uint8)
for i in range(256):
# calculating the new values
lookUpTable[0, i] = np.clip(pow(i / 255.0, 2) * 255.0, 0, 255)
# mapping the new values with the original
gamma_corrected_img = cv.LUT(img_original, lookUpTable)

# DOG
blur1 = cv.GaussianBlur(gamma_corrected_img, (3, 3), 1, borderType=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)
blur2 = cv.GaussianBlur(gamma_corrected_img, (7, 7), 2, borderType=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)

dog_img = cv.subtract(blur1, blur2)

# contrast equalisation
# step 1
alpha = 0.1
tau = 10
temp1 = pow(np.abs(dog_img), alpha)
meanImg = np.mean(temp1)

Contrast_Equa_step01 = dog_img / pow(meanImg, 1/alpha)
# step 2
minMat = np.abs(Contrast_Equa_step01)
minMat[minMat > tau] = tau
temp2 = pow(minMat, alpha)
meanImg2 = np.mean(temp2)
Contrast_Equa_step02 = Contrast_Equa_step01 / pow(meanImg2, 1/alpha)
CEqualized_img = tau * np.tanh((Contrast_Equa_step02/tau))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issue is that tau=10.0 is too large. It seems to work for me with tau=3.0 with my images normalized to floats in the range 0 to 1. Then at the end multiply by 255 and convert to uint8.

Here is my Python/OpenCV code. I have saved versions of the gamma corrected, DoG and first stage of the contrast equalization scaled by 255 to uint8 for viewing. I have also normalized the DoG (though not needed) by dividing by the largest absolute value to stretch values to -1 to 1. The normalization gives the DoG better contrast. I also swapped the order of the two blur images in the DoG to match his contrast polarity.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Reference: Enhanced Local Texture Feature Sets for Face Recognition Under Difficult Lighting Conditions by Xiaoyang Tan and Bill Triggs
# https://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2007/TT07/Tan-amfg07a.pdf

# read image as grayscale float in range 0 to 1
img = cv2.imread('face.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.float64) / 255.0

# set arguments
gamma = 0.2
alpha = 0.1
tau = 3.0

# gamma correction
img_gamma = np.power(img, gamma)
img_gamma2 = (255.0 * img_gamma).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# DOG
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gamma, (0,0), 1, borderType=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gamma, (0,0), 2, borderType=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
img_dog = (blur1 - blur2)
# normalize by the largest absolute value so range is -1 to 
img_dog = img_dog / np.amax(np.abs(img_dog))
img_dog2 = (255.0 * (0.5*img_dog + 0.5)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# contrast equalization equation 1
img_contrast1 = np.abs(img_dog)
img_contrast1 = np.power(img_contrast1, alpha)
img_contrast1 = np.mean(img_contrast1)
img_contrast1 = np.power(img_contrast1,1.0/alpha)
img_contrast1 = img_dog/img_contrast1

# contrast equalization equation 2
img_contrast2 = np.abs(img_contrast1)
img_contrast2 = img_contrast2.clip(0,tau)
img_contrast2 = np.mean(img_contrast2)
img_contrast2 = np.power(img_contrast2,1.0/alpha)
img_contrast2 = img_contrast1/img_contrast2
img_contrast = tau * np.tanh((img_contrast2/tau))

# Scale results two ways back to uint8 in the range 0 to 255
img_contrastA = (255.0 * (img_contrast+0.5)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_contrastB = (255.0 * (0.5*img_contrast+0.5)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# show results
cv2.imshow('Face', img)
cv2.imshow('Gamma', img_gamma2)
cv2.imshow('DoG', img_dog2)
cv2.imshow('CE1', img_contrast1)
cv2.imshow('CE_A', img_contrastA)
cv2.imshow('CE_B', img_contrastB)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('face_contrast_equalization_A.jpg', img_contrastA)
cv2.imwrite('face_contrast_equalization_B.jpg', img_contrastB)
```

One gets slightly different results depending upon how one scales the result from float back to uint8 in the range 0 to 255. The first method simply biases by 0.5 before multiplying by 255. The second multiplies by 0.5, then biases by 0.5 before multiplying by 255. Method A may be closer to what the authors of the reference achieved.

Scaling Method A:
[image]

Scaling Method B:
[image]

Adjust tau higher or lower to get the contrast you desire.

Comment: thnx for the reply, this is a better result and closer result to the original, although the tau is set to 3, compared to 10 in the original paper

Comment: One never knows what they actually implement, but only report the main concept. So the details may be slightly different thereby needing a slightly different tau. Also their implementation of the commands may have been coded differently (for example they say they process the full image, then crop out the given size center part). Or their implementation may have a sight bug or be biased or scaled differently.

Comment: I have modified my answer to include two different ways to scale the results back to uint8 in the range 0 to 255. The first method may be closer to what the authors of the reference achieved.

Comment: the first scaling method is closer to the one in the paper i think, i guess this is the solution I was looking for, thank you. 
Ps: I want to give you an up vote but it's not letting me, it says that I have to have at least 15 reputation and this is only my first post here. so thank you and sorry

Comment: OK. Come back later when you have enough points, if you remember. It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues.

1) You should normalize your image to the range 0 to 1 as floats throughout all your operations, then scale back to ints in the range 0 to 255 for the final result.

2) You have used gamma=2, not gamma=0.2

3) When computing the Gaussian blur using sigma values, you should set the dimensions to 0. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1

4) Typically, the DoG is biased to 0.5

Here is a simple example of computing the Gamma enhanced image and separately of the DoG image from your original face image in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('face.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype('float32') / 255.0

# gamma correction
img_gamma = img**0.2
img_gamma = (255.0 * img_gamma).clip(0,255).astype('uint8')

# DOG
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), 1, borderType=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), 2, borderType=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
# compute difference and bias to 0.5
img_dog1 = blur2 - blur1 + 0.5
img_dog1 = (255.0 * img_dog1).clip(0,255).astype('uint8')
# Or compute difference and add back to image as band pass boost filter
img_dog2 = blur2 - blur1 + img
img_dog2 = (255.0 * img_dog2).clip(0,255).astype('uint8')

# show results
cv2.imshow('Face', img)
cv2.imshow('Gamma', img_gamma)
cv2.imshow('DOG1', img_dog1)
cv2.imshow('DOG2', img_dog2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('face_gamma.jpg', img_gamma)
cv2.imwrite('face_dog1.jpg', img_dog1)
cv2.imwrite('face_dog2.jpg', img_dog2)
```

Gamma Enhance Result from input:

[image]

DoG Result1 from input:

[image]

DoG Result2 from input:

[image]

Perhaps these suggestions will help in your full processing.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I was just wondering is my contrast equalization method correct compared to the one in the paper, I've tried using the code that you provided with my contrast equalization method and it doesn't give a similar result.

Comment: In the paper, in Eqs 5 and 6, what are x' and y'?

Comment: i couldn't figure it out either, i didn't know what they represent because there wasn't any explanation about them in the paper, so i used x and y instead